# Export apt package list for reuse (debian)

Tags: debian, backup, apt, export

Is it possible to export a list of packages from a (Debian) server,

so I can *reuse* this list and simply hit `apt-get install <exported_package_list>`

on a different server?

Can I also pipe a textfile to `apt-get` like `apt-get install << list.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `--get-selections` and `--set-selections` options to `dpkg`.

You export a list of current selections using `dpkg --get-selections > my-selections`.

In order to restore the selections you first need to run `dpkg --set-selections < my-selections` and then `apt-get dselect-upgrade` to actually install the packages. Be aware that this will only restore the installed packages, but not any configuration or choices made during the install.